# How to replace items in a list with items from another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that replaces numbers in one list (from the user) with words (also from the user). For example 1 = "c", 2 = "z", 3 = "p".

This is what I have done so far:

```
wordlist = [None]
numbers = [0]
wordlist = input()
numbers = input()
wordlist.remove(None)
numbers.remove(0)
for numbers,item in enumerate(numbers):
    numbers.index(z) = wordlist.index
    z = z + 1
```

I`m not sure on what to do on the last couple of lines as no matter what I do it ends up just not working as intended.

I`m trying to do something along the lines of:
if numbers(z) is equal to wordlist.index then replace numbers(p) with wordlist.index(p) (with p being equal to the number of the index of the list of words (as long as all the words In the wordslist are different) and the number of the values in the "numbers"list (for example numbers = [1,2,3,1,4,5] then z would be the first and fourth value in this list))

Comment: `numbers.index(z)` returns the position of `z` (undeclared here): totally wrong.

Comment: You've tagged this as python 3. `input()` returns a string, which has no method `remove`. You might be mixing with python 2 `input()`, which reads input and evaluates it, returning the result. You'd overwrite `numbers` again in your for-loop, if you'd get there. And where's that `z` coming from? At this point you should step back, read the python tutorials again, and then come back to your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
wordlist=['apple','orange','banana']
numbers=[1,2,1]
ans=[]

for i in numbers:
    if i<len(wordlist):     #checks if value in numbers is below len of wordlist 
        ans.append(wordlist[i])

print(ans)
```

Output :

```
['orange', 'banana', 'orange']
```

If you want only unique values then instead of using list,use set

================================

If you want to take use input

```
wordlist = raw_input().split(' ')         #splits sentence into words using space as delimitor
numbers = [int(x) for x in raw_input().split()]    #int(x) is use for casting input string into integer type

ans=[]

for i in numbers:
    if i<len(wordlist):     #checks if value in numbers is below len of wordlist 
        ans.append(wordlist[i])

print(ans)
```

Input:

```
apple orange banana
1 2 1
```

Output:

```
['orange', 'banana', 'orange']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This code works by itself however when I try to apply this to the lists being from the user it no longer works as it just says "unorderable type". How do I fix this?

Comment: Also how do I do this so that the list remains in the order it was originally in as the words are in a different order than intended